# Time-constrained items recommendations in RecSys

Tags: recommendation-engine

I want to know if there is a coined term for a recommender system where the items to recommend are **bound in time by a start and end date** (ie: events).

While I know that time-sensitive recommender systems exist, they usually use the time of the day the user is in and the time previous items were interacted with to enhance the recommendations, which is not relevant in our case. Sequential recommendations are also not what we are searching for.

The main difference between a traditional system and these ones would be that almost every item to recommend would be **new** and thus, not in the dataset. Usually when a movie or a product is released, it can be recommended to many users over the years, improving the recommendation every time a user interacts with it, but in our case, an event can be recommended only for a bound time period (usually a couple of days).

Does a system with these types of restrictions have a name? Are there any more examples of this kind of system?